# Serving cache from multiple domain names

Tags: functions, plugin-w3-total-cache, uploads, cdn

I'm using W3 total cache for caching and I've many js files with sizes larger than 100KB in the cache folder. My idea is to serve cache folder from different subdomains (All files are hosted in the same VPS). This is for enabling concurrent downloads like a CDN.

If one js is serving from cache1.example.com, then the next should be from cache2.example.com. There will be up to 5 cache subdomains (for example), all are pointing to the same cache folder (wp-content/cache). I need to request each js files using different subdomains. I know that I can write a function to replace the cache-folder-address with single-subdomain-URL. But how do I achieve multiple-random-subdomains?

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: No. I couldn't.

Comment: I had to develop a custom solution for this. I use the WP Offload S3 plugin to offload all the media files to s3.